# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SecundaireSchool.Models.tblRapporten]'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[SecundaireSchool.Models.tblRapporten]`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `SecundaireSchool.Models.tblRapporten`.

Model **tblStudenten**

```
public partial class tblStudenten
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblStudenten()
    {
        this.tblRapportens = new HashSet<tblRapporten>();
    }

    public int student_id { get; set; }
    public string naam { get; set; }
    public string voornaam { get; set; }
    public string emailadres { get; set; }
    public string foto { get; set; }
    public int klas_id { get; set; }

    public virtual tblKlassen tblKlassen { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblRapporten> tblRapportens { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Klassen { get; set; }
}
```

Model **tblRapporten**

```
public partial class tblRapporten
{
    public int rapport_id { get; set; }
    public double punt { get; set; }
    public int vak_id { get; set; }
    public int student_id { get; set; }

    public virtual tblStudenten tblStudenten { get; set; }
    public virtual tblVakken tblVakken { get; set; }
}
```

StudentController

```
public ActionResult Report(int id)
    {
        return View(db.tblRapportens.Where(r => r.student_id == id).ToList());
    }
```

View Report

```
@model SecundaireSchool.Models.tblRapporten

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report";
}

<h2>Report</h2>

<div>
<h4>tblRapporten</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.punt)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.punt)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblStudenten.naam)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tblStudenten.naam)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblVakken.vak)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tblVakken.vak)
    </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.rapport_id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
```

I know that there is something wrong with the List of my controller, but I don't how to fix this.
Anyone?

Comment: Your view expects a single item and you are passing a list.

Comment: I just added my view.

Comment: Ok thnx. I fixed it :D

Answer (score 1):

Your view is expecting a model that is a single `SecundaireSchool.Models.tblRapporten` object, but your controller is assigning a `List<SecundaireSchool.Models.tblRapporten>` to your model. Change your model type in your view to `@model IList<SecundaireSchool.Models.tblRapporten>` and you're in business.

Comment: Either that or `return View(db.tblRapportens.Where(r => r.student_id == id)..FirstOrDefault());` assuming OP expects the query to return only one value :)